# Convert c++ vector to c-style pointer

Tags: c++, points

```
vector<vector<double> >a(3,vector<double>(4));
double *p = a[0];
```

Why this is wrong, `a[0]` is not the address of the first dimension of `a`?

Comment: yes, c++11 support it

Comment: You forgot to ask a question there Skippy

Comment: Don't put the answers in the question text.

Comment: You've edited the question to remove the question and replace it with (some kind of) answer. If you have an answer, then you could post it as an answer; but in any case you should leave the question intact so the rest of us can understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here

```
vector<vector<double> >a(3,vector<double>(4));
```

You defined a as a vector having 3 elements of type `vector<double>.` So a[0] has type `vector<double>.` vector is a user defined type. It is not a pointer.

Comment: You have stated loosely what is wrong. You have not helped explain how the OP can do what they want to do.

Comment: @thecoshman: Kinda difficult when the OP didn't tell us what he wants to do. I'd say Vlad hit it straight out of Red Square this time.